# Probability in Discrete Mathematics

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I need help with some probability questions. I answered the best I can but I'm not sure if any are correct.

**Consider the following character {1,3,5,7,9,a,b,c,d,e}**

(a) How many 6 character passwords?
**I said: $10 \choose 6$**

(b) How many 6 character passwords that contain exactly 2 numbers and exactly              4 characters?
**No Idea**

(c) How many 6 character passwords with no repeated characters?
**I said: $\frac{10!}{4!}$**

(d) How many 6 character passwords without the number 9?
**I said: $9^6$**

(e) How many 6 character passwords with at least one letter?
**I have no idea :(**

Comment: Order is important and presumably repeats are allowed, so all these answers are wrong!

Comment: Can you help me with the first one so I know where to go from there?

Comment: For each character of the password there are 10 choices, so $10^6$ possible 6 character passwords.

Comment: I fixed A (With your help) and D. Wouldn't C still be correct nonetheless?

Comment: Sorry, yes. (c) is correct: 10 choices for first character, then 9 for second and so on. (d) is also correct: 9 choices for each character.

Comment: Thank you :) How would I proceed on with B and E? For B, I thought that maybe I could do (Total Combination) - (6 number) - (5 number) - (4 number) - (3 number). But I believe I am thinking in a much more difficult way than it is

Comment: For (b), how many ways can you choose which 2 characters are numbers? Having done that there are then $5^6$ choices.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Like the math behind getting $5^6$? You asked how many ways I can choose 2 numbers, I'm not sure how to get that number though. Sorry, complete beginner at counting

Comment: Once you know which positions have letters and which have numbers, there are just 5 choices for each position. The answer for choosing 2 positions out of 6 is just ${6\choose2}=15$, but you could easily check that by hand.

Answer (score 2):

> > **Consider the following character {1,3,5,7,9,a,b,c,d,e}**
> >
> > (a) How many 6 character passwords?
>
> **I said: $10 \choose 6$**

That is the count of ways to select six distinct characters from the set of ten; however order is important and repeats are possible, so this is not the answer.

The task consists of a series of six choices each with ten options, so the count is ${10}^{6}$

---

> > (b) How many 6 character passwords that contain exactly 2 numbers and exactly              4 characters?
>
> **No Idea**

Break the task into three subtasks.   How many ways to make select 2 numerics, how many ways to select 4 alphabetics, and how may ways to select which of the six characters will be the two numerics?

> $$5^2\cdot 5^4\cdot \binom{6}{2}~=~ 5^6\binom 6 2$$

---

> > (c) How many 6 character passwords with no repeated characters?
>
> **I said: $\frac{10!}{4!}$**

Yes.   Alternatively written as $\binom{10}{6}6!$ or $^{10}{\rm P}_6$

---

> > (d) How many 6 character passwords without the number 9?
>
> **I said: $9^6$**

Indeed.

---

> > (e) How many 6 character passwords with at least one letter?
>
> **I have no idea :(**

Find how many 6 character passwords will have *no* letters, then use the law of complements.

Comment: This is actually very helpful. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

If the password is $123abc$ and a user types $abc123$ for the password, the user will not be given access.  So these two strings are different passwords.  Also, a letter is allowed to be repeated, for example $123aba$ is a valid password (I'm assuming this).  So, the number of passwords consisting of 6 letters is $10^6$ since each of the six blanks can be filled in 10 ways. This answers (a).

For (b), given six blanks, the two blanks containing the 2 numbers can be chosen in ${6 \choose 2}$ ways.  The number of ways to fill in these two blanks with numbers is $5^2$. And so on.

Think each of these problems as asking for the number of ways to fill in the six blanks, and this procedure of filling in the six blanks consists of a sequence of steps.  For each step, you need to find the number of ways to do the step.